# Most searched words in Elasticsearch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Does elasticsearch provide a way to keep track of popular keywords? For example, at a given time period, I would like to know the keywords that appear most frequently in queries. If elasticsearch does not have such a feature, what would be a good way to implement it using elasticsearch in a Springboot application?

I have my Springboot application and a separate module for elasticsearch wrapper and Kafka Producer. One approach I found is to generate an asynchronous event at my application level to Kafka and write a consumer and pull searched words into Elasticsearch. But if I have 10-20 applications, this method won't scale, as I would be required to write redundant code in all my applications. I don't want tight coupling between my modules either. Is there any approach, anyone can suggest?

Thanks!